# axios.post not finding localhost:5173

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I'm following this tutorial https://youtu.be/0aPLk2e2Z3g?t=5220 and I'm somehow stuck in the Register part (*Time in video = 1:27:00*).

For me, it is returning '**localhost:5173/auth/register 404 (Not Found)**'

the `package.json` has

```json
"proxy": "http://localhost:5173/api"
```

MySQL is configured to use the port 5173 and it is running.
I've try the suggestions from a similar post ([Proxy error: Could not proxy request /auth/register from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8800/api/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75540659/proxy-error-could-not-proxy-request-auth-register-from-localhost3000-to-http)) but I'm still getting the same error.

The files I got are the following ones.

**Index.jsx**

```js
import express from "express";
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.js";
import usersRoutes from "./routes/users.js";
import postsRoutes from "./routes/posts.js";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", usersRoutes);
app.use("/api/posts", postsRoutes);

app.listen(5173, () => {
  console.log("Server is running");
});
```

**auth.controller.js**

```js
import { db } from "../db.js";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

export const register = (req, rest) => {
  //CHECK EXISTING USER
  const q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? OR username = ?";

  db.query(q, [req.body.email, req.body.username], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return rest.json(err);
    if (data.error) return rest.status(409).json("User already exists");

    //Hash the password and create a new user
    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);

    const q = "INSERT INTO users (`username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (?)";
    const values = [req.body.username, req.body.email, hash];

    db.query(q, [values], (err, data) => {
      if (err) return rest.json(err);
      return rest.status(200).json("User has been created.");
    });
  });
};

export const login = (req, rest) => {};

export const logout = (req, rest) => {};
```

**auth.js**

```js
import express from "express";
import { register, login, logout } from "../controllers/auth.controller.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register", register);
router.post("/login", login);
router.get("/logout", logout);
export default router;
```

**Register.jsx**

```jsx
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Register = () => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputs((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/auth/register", inputs, {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      console.log(res);
    } catch (err) {}
  };
  return (
    <div className="auth">
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <form>
        <input
          required
          type="text"
          placeholder="Username"
          name="username"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          required
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          name="email"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          required
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          name="password"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Register</button>
        <p>This is an error!</p>
        <span>
          Have you got an account? <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
        </span>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

I even tried with a firewall rule.
Still no luck. Any idea what can be going on?
I will really appreciate it.

I tried playing with the URL from the proxy key in the package.json file.
I also tried editing the line `await axios.post('/auth/register', inputs` modifying the URL directly and also modifying the routes.

The code should create a user in the database in MySQL.

Comment: If your Express server is running on port 5173, what port is your React app dev server running on (ie, what URL is open in your browser)?

Comment: _"MySQL is configured to use the port 5173"_... did you mean _Express_? MySQL is a database server and typically binds to port 3306

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. The proxied requests work just fine and even when I simulate a 404 response from the server, the error in the browser console shows `http://localhost:3000/auth/register 404`, that being the React dev server port and not the proxied address.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this agent to your axios post request

```js
import http from 'http';

let agent = new http.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false
});
```

?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The HTTP agent is not available in the browser